# Carbon design system global scss takes forever to build

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, carbon-design-system

I'm trying to apply g10 theme from Carbon Design System(Vue). But it takes about 12-15 mins to compile every time I save a file.

- Is there a way to add styles for only the components I use?
- If not, how do I reduce the build time?
- Is there a way to remove watch on scss files so I can save compile time when working in Vue files?

```
@import "@carbon/themes/scss/themes";

$carbon--theme: $carbon--theme--g10;

// Use the gray 10 theme
@include carbon--theme();

@import "carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/styles";
@import "@carbon/grid/scss/grid";
```

Answer (score 1):

We workaround this by having all the Carbon related styling in the `App.vue` file, which imports another component (e.g. `AppContent.vue`) which contains the content for the entire app.

This means that the Carbon styling is only compiled when you make changes to the `App.vue`, and as everything is in `AppContent.vue`, you'll only need to make changes to this file rather than `App.vue`.

`App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <app-content></app-content>
</template>

<script>
import AppContent from "./AppContent.vue";
export default {
  components: { AppContent }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "./styles/carbon";
@import "./styles/_carbon.scss";
</style>
```

`AppContent.vue`:

```
<template>
  <!-- the rest of your app -->
</template>

<script>
  // the rest of your app
</script>

<style>
  /* the rest of your app */
</style>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in app.vue. How did you solve it?
```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: The "content" component has been registered but not used (vue/no-unused-components) at src/App.vue:13:5:
  11 |   name: "app",
  12 |   components: {
> 13 |     content: Content
     |     ^
  14 |   }
  15 | };
  16 | </script>
```

Comment: I've updated my reply changing the `Content` words to `AppContent`, I think that using `Content` can mess it up and give you the error you're having